# Consulta não retorna fetch_array

Tags: php, array, query

Estou tentando fazer uma consulta porém, apesar da query funcionar bem no PHPMyAdmin no navegador retorna a mensagem abaixo:

> Fatal error : Call to undefined method PDOStatement::fetch_array() in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\final\inc\projecao.php on line 73

Meu código está assim:

```
 $sql = BD::conn()->prepare("SELECT 
    sjy_empresas.nick, 
    pe_orclinhas.dc, 
    pe_orcgrupos.grupo_orcamento, 
    pe_orclinhas.orclinha, 
    pe_orclinhas.id_orclinha, 
    pe_premorc.exercicio, 
    pe_premorc.emp, 
    pe_premorc.anterior, 
    pe_premorc.prj
    FROM sjy_empresas 
    INNER JOIN pe_orcgrupos 
    INNER JOIN pe_orclinhas ON pe_orcgrupos.id_orca = pe_orclinhas.orcgrupo
    INNER JOIN pe_premorc ON pe_orclinhas.id_orclinha = pe_premorc.linhabud
    AND sjy_empresas.id_empresa = pe_premorc.emp
    WHERE pe_premorc.emp = ?
    AND pe_premorc.exercicio = ?
    AND pe_orclinhas.id_orclinha = ?");

    $sql->execute(array($emp, $exercicio, $ans));                               
    $dt = $sql->fetch();

    $nick    = $dt('nick'); // Essa é a linha 75
```

Comment: Você já deu um `var_dump($dt)` ???

Comment: Sim e os campos estão vindos normalmente. Só que como string:  array(9) { ["nick"]=> string(14) "Exemplo TOY SP" ["dc"]=> string(1) "X" ["grupo_orcamento"]=> string(9) "Show Room" ["orclinha"]=> string(5) "Etios" ["id_orclinha"]=> string(3) "460" ["exercicio"]=> string(4) "2018" ["emp"]=> string(1) "4" ["anterior"]=> string(4) "0.00" ["prj"]=> string(4) "0.00" }

Comment: Então é `$dt['nick']` entendeu?

Comment: Ops!!! entendi sim. Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDO

```
$dt = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Manual: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.fetch.php

Sem PDO

```
$dt = $sql->fetch_assoc();
```

Imprimindo na tela:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($dt);
```

Manual: https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: Agora está dando esse erro Fatal error
: Function name must be a string in
D:\xampp\htdocs\final\inc\projecao.php
on line
75

Comment: Erro de tipo de dados. Veja a linha 75 do `projecao.php`... ou poste o código.

Comment: O código está postado mas vou postar aqui também     $sql->execute(array($emp, $exercicio, $ans));                               
    $dt = $sql->fetch();

    $nick    = $dt('nick'); // Essa é a linha 75

Comment: Confirma primeiro se está sendo gerado o array `print_r($dt);
die();`... o que provavelmente está... e também creio que seja `$nick = $dt['nick'];` pois está imprimindo um array. Mas vá por partes, entenda o que está fazendo, que irá dar certo !

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql->execute(array($emp, $exercicio, $ans));                               
$dt = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Agora está dando esse erro   Fatal error
: Function name must be a string in
D:\xampp\htdocs\final\inc\projecao.php
on line
75